# UINavigationController won't pushViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers. One is called LoginVC which also is my rootviewcontroller, the other one is named SignUpVC.

In my AppDelegate I have set my UINavigationbar like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginVC())

    return true
}
```

then in my LoginVC I use this to get my SignUpVC to show but it doesn't work.

```
@objc func handleShowSignUp() {
    let signUpVC = SignUpVC()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpVC, animated: true)
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the LoginVC display? Not sure if it is just a typo but you also need to add `window.makeKeyAndVisible()`. Besides that it looks about right.

Comment: Check if `LoginVC` has `navigationController`

Comment: did you remove storyboard from main storyboard on your .plist ? The lack of   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() on your appdelegate makes me thing like you are opening default storyboard initial VC, but you think you opened it from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys!
I added window.makeKeyAndVisible() and also removed "Main" from my .plist but it still won't work.

Comment: @MattiasTörnqvist my answer have  worked ?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the app is not launching from the AppDelegate. If I change to
            window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = SignUpVC()
Even then the app will launch to LoginVC. 

Maybe I've set the entry point some other place? I'm trying to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the File SceneDelegate, of this manner:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow? // create Window

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let LoginVC = ViewController() //create your viewController
        nav.pushViewController(contentView, animated: true) 
               if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
                   let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                   window.rootViewController = LoginVC
                   SceneDelegate.window = window
                   window.makeKeyAndVisible()
               }
    }
```

important: you can check the `UIWindowScene`

Comment: I'm doing this for iOS 12, it's part of a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Directly initializing LoginVC() and SignUpVC() is kind of wrong. Try something like this if you are using storyboards

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil)
let nav = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() //if you want the initial one

let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil)
let someVC: SomeViewController = giftStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController") as! SomeViewController //don't forget to set identifier on interfacebuilder
```

If you are using only .xib

```
let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
```

then try to pushing it to navigation controller

Comment: I'm not using Storyboards, trying to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick in the SceneDelegate-file:

```
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let scene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginVC())
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```